# Difference between MeshRenderer and Renderer Component

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code

```
GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds
```

and this

```
GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds
```

Tried to [search](https://answers.unity.com/questions/929396/whats-the-difference-between-gameobjectrenderer-an.html) what is the difference between both components but didn't found any helpful thing.?

Comment: MeshRenderer inherits from Renderer so is more specific renderer for meshes? I would expect those to return the same object if the rendered is a mesh renderer

Comment: If people would have a look into the [Unity API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) from time to time they wouldn't need to ask this kind of questions :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Difference between MeshRenderer and Renderer Component

There is `MeshRenderer` for displaying 3D Objects/models. There is also `SpriteRenderer` for displaying 2D images like sprites. The `Renderer` component is simply a base class that  `MeshRenderer`  and `SpriteRenderer` derives from. The `bounds` variable is declared in Renderer so accessing it from `MeshRenderer` or `Renderer`  will give you the-same value. Because `SpriteRenderer` also derives from `Renderer`, you have access to other variables from the `Renderer`  class.

So, `GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().bounds` and `GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds` are doing the-same things. The first one will get the `MeshRenderer` and access the `bounds` variable from the `Renderer` parent class. The second one will get the `Renderer` and access the `bounds` variable directly from it.

It's worth noting that you cannot attach `Renderer` to a GameObject. You can access it from a GameObject but cannot attach it.

For example, you can do this:

```
GetComponent<Renderer>()
```

but you cannot do this:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<Renderer>()
```

and will get the exception below:

> Cannot add component of type 'Renderer' because it is abstract. Add
>   component of type that is derived from 'Renderer' instead.

Only the components that derive from `Renderer` are what what can be attached to a GameObject. For example, `SpriteRenderer` and `MeshRenderer`.